# Couldn't find package dd

Tags: asus, dd

I have run sudo apt-get update and upgrade, but apt-get install dd fails as above.
I am using Xandros on a asus eeepc.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and the official derivatives are supported here. Sorry.

Comment: Do a `which dd` or `ls /bin/dd` .  Perhaps switch to plain Ubuntu Server?

Comment: @mikewhatever dd is part of the default Ubuntu install being part of coreutils. How is this off topic???! Informing the OP that dd is probably already installed (and explaining that dd is part of coreutils) and guiding him on how to use it is the correct approach to this question not closing it as off topic!

Comment: @mikewhatever I just noticed that he is asking about Xandros, which per our current guidelines IS off topic.

Answer (score 4):

The "dd" utility is part of the [coreutils](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/coreutils) package, and should be installed by default already.

If it's missing from your system, please provide error messages.

Answer (score 1):

`dd` should already be installed.

Try using `man dd` to make sure.